# wordpress (woocommerce) add image to media library programmatically python

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic

So what I am trying to do is to link an image to a product in woocommerce.

first the image is downloaded by python script and put in a folder.

I've inserted into the DB a post of type attachment with a location to the file in it and the post parent as the product i want to link it to.

I then added the attachment id on the products post (mysql)

but the picture doesnt show up and in the media library it shows up as blank. what else do i need to do?

Comment: Does it show up a blank because it's shows you the thumbnail url instead of the real image full size url ? :)

Comment: @Jean-RémiLARCELET-PROST it shows up as a broken picture in the media sectoin on the backend of the wordpress site, so i assume it showing up blank as its not fully entered into the db correctly

Comment: Check if your thumbnail URL in admin is really as thumbnail URL and not a full size URL please :)